# Django DRF AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `added_email` on serializer `UserMailListSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

ps. I'm sorry that the sentences are weird because I'm not familiar with English.

An error occurs when you add an email to your mailing list.

error message

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `added_email` on serializer `UserMailListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'added_email'.
```

After AttributeError, the database contains the values you want to save correctly, and after refresh, check the mailing list with Get to get the values. Errors seem to occur only when added to the list.

Model.py

```
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ model manager """

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """ create user """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("valid email")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password=None):
        """ create admin """
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ user account model """
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name='email')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='username')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='subscription_date')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'accounts'

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class UserMailList(models.Model):
    """ mailling list model """
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    added_email = models.EmailField()
    added_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

serializer.py (Mailling list )

```
class UserMailListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ usermailing list serializer """

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserMailList
        fields = ('id', 'user_account', 'added_email', 'added_name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user_account':  {'read_only': True},
            'added_name': {'read_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ (post) add mailing list """

        if models.UserAccount.objects.filter(email=validated_data['added_email']).exists():
            if not models.UserMailList.objects.filter(added_email=validated_data['added_email']).exists():
                user = models.UserMailList(
                    added_email=validated_data['added_email'].text(),
                    added_name=models.UserAccount.objects.get(email=validated_data['added_email']).name,
                )
            else:
                return "duplicate message"
        else:
            return "nonexistent message"

        user.save()

        return user
```

views.py (mailing list viewset)

```
class UserMailListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ handle user mailing list """

    queryset = models.UserMailList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserMailListSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permission.UpdateOwnAccount, IsAuthenticated)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code right here

```
            else:
                return "duplicate message"
        else:
            return "nonexistent message"
```

Doesn't exactly raise any error, so the other part of the code thinks it successfully created User and tried to use your error string as an object.

If we look at documentation right here
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L905

they used something like

```
raise TypeError(msg)
```

to raise any error message. So, instead of `return "duplicate message"` you should use

```
raise TypeError("Duplicate Message")
```

There are many exceptions that might be more appropriate, but as long as you're raising error it should be fine.